# Change of coordinate system in terms of tangent spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, coordinate-systems

I have encountered an interesting equation while reading Spivak's *Comprehensive Introduction to Differential Geometry* (vol. 1, chapter 4).

The situation is as follows: we are considering coordinate systems on $\mathbb{R}^n$ which are linear transformations. Let $x$ be such a coordinate system with $x(v_i)=e_i$ (of course $x(a^1v_1+\ldots+a^n v_n)=(a^1,\ldots,a^n)$ ). Now, if $x'$ is another such coordinate system, then by means of linear algebra we clearly have $ {x'}^{j} = \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_{ij}x^{i} $ for certain $a_{ij}$.

The non-trivial part starts when the author gives the explicit formula for coefficients:
$a_{ij}\;=\; \frac{\partial{x'}^{j}}{\partial{x}^{i}}$,
so that ${x'}^{j}=\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{\partial {x'}^{j}}{\partial x^{i}} \: x^{i}$. It is even more disturbing since the author remarks on this result as somehow obvious.

I would be grateful for any hints on how to obtain such a formula for $a_{ij}$. Also, how should I understand it in terms of tangent spaces?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The coefficients $\partial x'^j/\partial x^i$ are the entries of the Jacobian matrix for the change of coordinates.  You're probably familiar with the Jacobian in 2 or 3 dimensions; this is just an $n$-dimensional version.  Writing out the matrix might make it easier to verify for yourself that $x'^j=\sum_{i=1}^n \partial x'^j/\partial x^i x^i$.

Answer (score 2):

Take the equality $x'^j = \sum_{i=1}^n a_{ij}x^i$, and apply $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^k}$ on both sides. We get $$\frac{\partial x'^j}{\partial x^k} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x^k}\sum_{i=1}^n a_{ij}x^i = \sum_{i=1}^n a_{ij}\frac{\partial x^i}{\partial x^k} = \sum_{i=1}^n a_{ij}\delta^i_k = a_{kj}.$$Rename $k \to i$ if you want to get $\frac{\partial x'^j}{\partial x^i} = a_{ij}$.

Comment: OK, I was trying to solve this problem in the very same way. But still, I do not think that is a strict, formal reasoning. Since $x'$ is a function on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ (treated as a manifold) and $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{k}}$ is a vector of the tangent bundle, then what does it mean to "apply" tangent vector to a simple function? It all would make sense if $x'$ belonged to the cotangent bundle, but it clearly does not.

Comment: Of course, I meant the section of cotangent bundle. Sorry for the mistake.

Comment: Tangent vectors act in functions as derivations. If $M$ is a smooth manifold and $f \in C^\infty(M)$, if $v_p \in T_pM$, then we have $v_p(f) \stackrel{\cdot}{=} {\rm d}f_p(v_p) \in T_{f(p)}\Bbb R \cong \Bbb R$.